# HTML Element translates down on adding content to it

Tags: html, css, translation

Today, I was working on a game known as `Tic Tac Toe`, in which I used the following code:

```js
let init = () => {
  const [...boxes] = document.getElementsByClassName('col');
  let insert = (box, oper) => {
    box.innerHTML = 'X';
  };

  boxes.forEach(box => {
    box.addEventListener('click', event => {
      insert(event.target, 1);
    });
    box.innerHTML = '';
  });
};

window.onload = init();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.ctn {
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 7vh 0;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.col {
  padding: 0;
  font: 800 64pt normal;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class='ctn'>
    <div class='row'>
      <p class='col'></p>
      <p class='col'>D</p>
      <p class='col'></p>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <p class='col'></p>
      <p class='col'></p>
      <p class='col'></p>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <p class='col'></p>
      <p class='col'></p>
      <p class='col'></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src='./script.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, I added an `Event Listener` with every box. But, when I actually click on the box, the **box translates down**. Further, when I click **all three boxes** of the same row, they actually translates up to the **initial** position!

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It has something to do with the box that gets put around the letter, but goes away when the row is all filled in.

Comment: `vertical-align: top;` to col will fix the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `inline-block` - add `vertical-align: middle;` to `col`:

```js
let init = () => {
  const [...boxes] = document.getElementsByClassName('col');
  let insert = (box, oper) => {
    box.innerHTML = 'X';
  };

  boxes.forEach(box => {
    box.addEventListener('click', event => {
      insert(event.target, 1);
    });
    box.innerHTML = '';
  });
};

window.onload = init();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.ctn {
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 7vh 0;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.col {
  padding: 0;
  font: 800 64pt normal;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class='ctn'>
  <div class='row'>
    <p class='col'></p>
    <p class='col'>D</p>
    <p class='col'></p>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <p class='col'></p>
    <p class='col'></p>
    <p class='col'></p>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <p class='col'></p>
    <p class='col'></p>
    <p class='col'></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: I would recommend using `flex` or `grid` for this kind of layout.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem :)

Comment: to be more accurate it should be any value of vertical-align different from baseline/sub/super ... middle,bottom, top are all valid in this case